# Error: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. At WinServiceProject.WinService.OnStart(String[] args) in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\WinServiceProject\WinService.cs:line 515

`{`
                            `string[] stringArray = row["Version"].ToString().Split('.');`

```
        Line 515 -----> switch (stringArray[0] + "." + stringArray[1] + ".")
                        {
                            case "11.0.":
                                sqlServerVersion = "SQL Server 2012";
                                file.WriteLine("SQL Server 2012");
                                break;

                            case "10.50.":
                                sqlServerVersion = "SQL Server 2008 R2";
                                file.WriteLine("SQL Server 2008 R2");
                                break;

                            case "10.0.":
                                sqlServerVersion = "SQL Server 2008";
                                file.WriteLine("SQL Server 2008");
                                break;

                            case "9.00.":
                                sqlServerVersion = "SQL Server 2005";
                                file.WriteLine("SQL Server 2005");
                                break;
                        }
                    }`
```

If Someone can help me please... thanks.

Comment: What is return `row["Version"].ToString()`?

Comment: return the SQL Server Internal Version... its that the reason that I made the cases cuz this show something like 11.0.2100.60.

Comment: you are so funny... this is a Windows Service... try to debug... the only way to debug its with NotePad... If people only will post to say any thing that dont help me... please dont post

Comment: @ManuelFdz You can use your debugger on a windows service you created. It's just a slightly different process than the normal F5 debugging. What on earth are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `stringArray` contains less than two elements.That is your problem, you need to make sure it contains at least two elements before `switch` statement.BTW, if you just want to append a `dot` to the end, you don't need `String.Split`, just use `Insert` method:

```
string str  = row["Version"].ToString();
str = str.Insert(str.Length, ".");

switch(str)
{
   ...
}
```

Or simply use *string concatenation*:  `string str = row["Version"].ToString() + "."`;

Comment: I will try with the second option cuz the other show an error... thanks, I need wait 15 minutes to mark the answer

Comment: thanks man, this help me to continue with another step... great day!!